# Different response for same API but different method (GET and POST)

Tags: rest, web-services, post, get, http-method

I think this is a classic and typical question but I didn't find its answer.

In my knowledge, the **POST** method is used to send data to the server with request parameter in message body to make it secure. And **GET** method is to retrieve data with parameters in the URL.
But what I didn't understand is how the same api may have different behavior by just changing the method.

Here is an example. I use SoapUI 5.5.0, this is the link of the api: https://reqres.in/api/users/1

when I use GET method I get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "George",
    "last_name": "Bluth",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
  }
}
```

and by changing only the method to POST, I get this:

```
{
   "id": "244",
   "createdAt": "2020-02-27T14:30:32.100Z"
}
```

(the id and date changes each time)
as described in this link https://reqres.in/ that it is creating an instance and we can add parameters..

BUT, can any one explain how is it technically possible to have different behavior with different methods on the same URL.

Comment: If you familiar with MVC pattern, I can explain it very easy. `POST https://reqres.in/api/users` is one controller; `GET https://reqres.in/api/users` is another controller. They are two different controller, eventhough they shared the same address. Usually, `GET https://reqres.in/api/users` is for index (all record), and `GET https://reqres.in/api/users/<id>` is to show one record. Both are two different controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my knowledge, the POST method is used to send data to the server with request parameter in message body to make it secure. And GET method is to retrieve data with parameters in the URL.

That's probably getting in your way.

HTTP Requests are messages; each message starts with a [request-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1)

```
method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF
```

> The request-target identifies the target resource upon which to apply the request

> The method token indicates the request method to be performed on the target resource.

You can think of it being like a function call

```
GET(target-resource)
POST(target-resource, message-body)
```

Or equivalently you can think of the resources as objects that share an understanding of message semantics

```
target-resource.GET()
target-resource.POST(message-body)
```

> But what I didn't understand is how the same api may have different behavior by just changing the method.

The same way that an api can exhibit different behavior by just changing the request-target.

In HTTP, the request-line is literally human readable text that the server will parse.  Having parsed the request-line, the server program can then branch to whatever code it wants to use to do the work, based on the values it found in the message.

In many frameworks (Spring, Rails) the branching logic is provided by the framework code; your bespoke handlers only need to be correctly registered and the framework ensures that each request is forwarded to the correct handler.

Answer (score 1):

> how is it technically possible to have different behavior with
>   different methods on the same URL

for the technical possibility, you can look at the spring framework's [answer to this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

You can have a controller that is accessible on a single url but can contacted in four says, `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`. To do this, Spring provides the annotations `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, `@PutMapping`, `@DeleteMapping`.

All the requests are sent to the same url and Spring works out which method to call based on the verb.

Answer (score 0):

In Restful APIs, verbs have very important meaning.

`GET`: Retrieve data
`POST`: Create a new entity with the request's body
`PUT`: Replace an entity with the request's body
`PATCH`: Update some properties of an entity with the request's body. A.K.A. Partial update

In your case, changing the verb from `get` to `post` has the effect of creating a new entity with ID `1`. That's why you get a response with the newly created ID and a `createdAt` timestamp.

Comment: but in the link I have the parameter 1 (for the id) , then I get a response with another id. and what I still didn't understand, is how the same API may have different methods. what I know is that the api have one method. (I am still discovering the Restful API's world) I can't even find an example of developing a single API with more than one method

Comment: In Rest, the Url is used to reference a resource and the HTTP verb dictates the operation you want to perform on that resource. So, 1 Url may represent multiple server methods.